# Calling a method of a global object from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found out how to solve the problem but I could not understand what the problem was although, I know why it is working now.

Here is the code that works:

```
function onReceive(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var m = $("<p/>", {
      "class": "message",
      html: json[i].message
    });

    $("#messages").append(m);
  }
}
```

I quote from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp):

```
var carName = " Volvo";

// code here can use carName
function myFunction() {
  // code here can use carName
}
```

My question is, why wouldn't this work?

```
messages = $("#messages");

function onReceive(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var m = $("<p/>", {
      "class": "message",
      html: json[i].message
    });

    messages.append(m);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from your examples, but most probably you're calling `messages = $("#messages")` outside of the onload handler, in which case it returns nothing.

Comment: messages = $("#messages"); i think you need to add `var ` ??

Comment: It looks like it just works :) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A1rPun/99psrp7u/)

Comment: @georg Like you said, I enclosed all my code within a `$("document").ready(function() {...});` block. It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using `messages = $("#messages");` before DOM ready. So at that time your javaScript not able to get `$("#messages")` and you are using `onReceive()` function after DOM load so it's working inside your function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get element when it is part of page already.

You could wrap $ call with document ready callback, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    messages = $("#messages");
});
```

Otherwise selector return empty collection (no element with id `messages` found).

Such wrapper is not required in event handlers, because event callbacks are always called after document is ready.